# NextJS: dev only pages

Tags: html, next.js, hidden

I would like to create a `/storybook` page. But this page is for development purpose only. I mean, I don't want this page to be accessible in production mode.

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. I think you have a couple of approaches.

**With Next.js 9.5+**

You can use `rewrite` to make sure traffics to `/storybook` will go to your 404 page.

```js
// next.config.js
// more configs
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/storybook',
        destination: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/404' : '/storybook',
      }
    ];
  },
// more configs
```

**With Next.js 10+**

You can use the `notFound` attribute in your `getServerSideProps` or `getStaticProps`. For more information, you can find the [doc here](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#redirect-and-notfound-support-for-getstaticprops--getserversideprops)

```js
// or getServerSideProps
export function getStaticProps() {
  return {
    // returns the default 404 page with a status code of 404 in production
     notFound: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
  }
}
```

**With Custom Server**

Depends on the server framework, you can do the redirect to 404 there.

Comment: Do the imports from the dev pages make their way into the final build when you run `npm run build`?

Comment: I can't suggest edits for your answer, so I'll just write it here: you should return `{ notFound: true }` or `{ props: {} }`. Returning `{ props: { notFound: true } }` does not work.

Comment: @EddyVinck thank you for pointing out. I update the answer.

Comment: next v12 requires `{ props: { notFound: true } }` it seems